# How can I allow access to my Django web server to someone on the same VPN network?

Tags: django, web, server, webserver, vpn

I have a Django app that I'm running with

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

I'm also connected to a corporate VPN for work.

I can access this app by going to `localhost:8000/admin` or `192.x.x.x:8000/admin` in my browser, that's fine. What I want to do is provide access to this Django app to my coworker, who is connected to the same VPN as me. How can I do this?

EDIT: also want to note I am on a Mac and have the django settings file with

```
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

Comment: It probably depends on how much control over network configurations you have. However- using a tool like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) provides a great solution out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I think is a network issue you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32103885/not-able-to-access-local-server-running-after-vpn-connection), so you simply can use a third-party app to share your localhost app with others, you can use this app for free: Pagekite or Ngrok or other alternatives.